# Unable to get sender email notification after completed document by recipients using DocuSign API

Tags: php, curl, docusignapi

Unable to get notification via email to sender after completing document by recipients using DocuSign API

I have created envelope using DocuSign API. The envelope created successfully and recipients got notification from that envelope request but sender not receive any notification via email when recipient complete the document.
My code sample is given bellow

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://account-d.docusign.com/v2.1/accounts/b15b77b0-9345-4780-bfc1-440b37991820/envelopes?change_routing_order=true',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "Base64 code of my pdf file",
            "documentId": "5865888",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "test pdf"
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "test pdf",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "name": "User full name",
                "email": "user@gmail.com",
                "recipientId": "8959555"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "send "
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: [{"key":"Authorization","value":"Bearer {{accessToken}}"}]'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Please help me how to get sender notification via email after completed document by recipient.
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked Settings -> Signing and Sending -> Email Preferences and then check the "for sender" -> "An envelope is complete" checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I have checked Email Preferences. "An envelope is complete" already checked for sender. But unable to get notification to sender after completed document by recipient.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben mentioned, this is controlled under "My Preferences" top-right.
If you have this, then the only other option is that you're not sending/configuration the same account. Confirm you're in the same exact **developer** account that you use to generate the access token you used from the API.
If you still don't get emails, they may be blocked by your mail server. You can contact DocuSign support if you exhausted all these things.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have marked checked above all checklists and still not receive completed mail to cc person or admin only the signer person gets a notification but we want cc person can also get a notification when the signature done

@Inbar Gazit

Comment: https://prnt.sc/EowKwYzgKtbR